# Can I use Apache Flight for sending and receiving byte data?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, kryo, apache-arrow-flight

I am using Apache Http client for sending and receiving data from server. For large requests I have chunked the data manually and sending them one by one . Is there any way to send these data chunks parallelly. That's when I read about Apache flight. Is it helpful in my case ?

Currently I am sending and receiving byte data using simple apache http client to my spring boot rest endpoint.
I have read that apache flight uses parallel data streams for faster byte data transfer.
Can I use apache flight for sending and receiving data ?
Byte data is nothing but Kryo serialized java objects which I will be de-serializing on server.
I have also analyzed the Apache Arrow data format , but currently it doesn't it in my design.
Kindly guide.

Regards,
Sameer K